# How to deal with extbase filter arguments and cHash caching?

Tags: caching, typo3, extbase

I have an extbase extension with filter arguments, sorting and pagination. Should I deactivate the cache for the whole action (by settings the action in the ext_localconf.php)?

But the page without any parameters could be cached in my opinion (espacially staticfilecache could be used). Also the pages without any filter could be cached.

So how to deal with this? Should I use [FE][cacheHash][cachedParametersWhiteList] or [FE][cacheHash][excludedParameters]?

If I add all parameters to cachedParametersWhiteList I get a different view for all arguments. But should I really cache all filter combinations?

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'][FE][cacheHash][cachedParametersWhiteList] = 'tx_csshop_pi3[page],tx_csshop_pi3[direction],tx_csshop_pi3[filter],tx_csshop_pi3[sort],tx_csshop_pi3[addFilter][name],tx_csshop_pi3[addFilter][value],tx_csshop_pi3[removeFilter][name],tx_csshop_pi3[removeFilter][value]'
```

Parameter that could be cached:

```
tx_csshop_pi3[page]
```

Parameter that if set, the caching should be disabled:

```
- tx_csshop_pi3[direction]
- tx_csshop_pi3[filter]
- tx_csshop_pi3[addFilter][name]
- tx_csshop_pi3[addFilter][value]
- tx_csshop_pi3[removeFilter][name]
- tx_csshop_pi3[removeFilter][value]
- tx_csshop_pi3[sort]
```